Chain slipping from a table using calculus

A chain of mass $M$ and length $L$ is kept on a table with $l$ part hanging of it. If its final length is $l'$ ,what will be the final velocity of the chain?

I do know how to solve this using the definition of change in potential energy, however i'm terrible confused about how to solve this using integration. I'll list two ways of how i tried solving

Using basic definition of Work Done :

For any element dx of mass dm on the hanging part at a length x from the top:$$dW = F_g.dx$$ $$dW_{dm}=dmg.dx$$ $$W_{dm}=\int_x^{x+l'-l}{dmg.dx}=dmg(l'-l)$$ Now for work done of all dm :
$$W=\int_0^l\frac{M}{L}dxg(l'-l)$$ $$=\frac{M}{L}g(l'-l)l$$
However this is wrong.
2.Using COM(Centre of Mass):
Let the centre of mass be at a distance x from the top
$$dW= F_g.dx$$ $$dW_{com} = \frac{M}{L}2xg.dx$$ $$W_{com}=\int_{l/2}^{l'/2}{\frac{M}{L}2xg.dx}$$ $$=\frac{M}{L}g((\frac{l'}{2})^2-(\frac{l}{2})^2)$$
This is also wrong. What's wrong here? It is greatly appreciated if this question is not marked as a homework question as this clearly asks about the clarity of two concepts..

[The correct method if required for reference:]
$$U_{f(com)}-U_{i(com)}=-W_{com}$$ $$U_{f(com)}=(\frac{M}{L}l')\frac{l'}{2}g = \frac{Ml'^2}{2L}g; U_{i(com)}=(\frac{M}{L}l)\frac{l}{2}g = \frac{Ml^2}{2L}g$$ Therefore Work Done $= \frac{Ml'^2}{2L}g - \frac{Ml^2}{2L}g$

